# Short keyword-only HTML Title or Long Titles - to rank better

Tags: keywords, title

I would like to know if **long html titles should be used** for pages instead of *google adwords keyword tool based* **short titles** - for SEO / Ranking purposes?

I feel that it is a **mistake** to use short html titles  made up of 2-3 words **strictly based on google adwords keyword tool**. I have tried using short ones based on what the adwords keyword tool suggested, but **that has served me no purpose** as I cannot see my website pages anywhere in the search results. Please correct me, if wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Like everything else - **make it with users in mind**.

Don't worry about what machines will make of your title, worry about what people will make of it and write the most appropriate title for the article/page/site, this should normally be both descriptive and brief.

If you bend your copy to suit Google too much you will end up with pages with a lot of traffic but a massive bounce rate.

Answer (score 1):

This article pretty much lays it all out for SEO best practice title tags:

http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/title-tag

To sum up don't go over 70 characters and remember that search engines give more credit to keywords at the beginning of a text block than at the end so put your competitive phrases first and phrases you would expect to rank well (such as your brand) at the end.